# Create OData service definition as YAML intead of EDMX?

Tags: yaml, odata, edmx, sap

I use an SAP OData (v2) service and request the EDMX service definition by calling
`https://service-url/$metadata`.

The service definition is quite complex and I have trouble to understand it the XML format.
It starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema Namespace="XYZ_SRV" xml:lang="de" sap:schema-version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
```

To make it better readable, I would like to download or convert the definition as (into) the YAML format. Like the YAMLs provided for the services on the SAP hub (eg. https://api.sap.com/api/BusinessPartners/overview)

How can I reach this?

Comment: What SAP software do you use to create your OData service?

Comment: @SandraRossi: I don't know. I don't create it - I just consume it.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely you will be able to do that if you do not own this service.

You can try, however, utilize Swagger-based SAP API Designer, which is a part of CloudFoundry service [SAP API Management](https://help.sap.com/viewer/66d066d903c2473f81ec33acfe2ccdb4/Cloud/en-US/0aef7634df25497896abf18faac8a1ce.html)

[image]

You must buy subscription to it (or try in trial mode), then enable API Management in dashboard and in finally Designer you can parse the service metadata and then download it in the suitable format

[image]

I notice that I didn't try it myself, but just heard that such facility exists, so rather try to read [API Management](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_CLOUD_PLATFORM_API_MANAGEMENT/Cloud/en-US) documentation, than asking me.